# Error SDK Facebook

Tags: android-studio, react-native, sdk

Estoy trabajando en android studio, modificando un archivo de una app que realizaron en react-native, sin embargo al querer realizar la importacion de el sdk de facebook me arroja un error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo solucionarlo

este es el codigo de esa parte:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;


project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.platzi2"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'


    // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Dentro del archivo `build.gradle` no se deben agregar los `import` de clases**, se deben agregar las dependencias, por ejemplo:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
}
```

Elimina estas lineas dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle`:

```
import com.android.build.OutputFile
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
```

los `import` de las clases se deben agregar dentro de las clases donde sea necesario.

Comment: lo voy a intentar es que la guia de facebook es confunsa

Comment: En realidad es sencillo implementar el SDK agrega la dependencia dentro de tu build.gradle "implementation...." y en tus clases puedes usar sus clases mediante import. :)

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.